# Shortcut for cloning a tab

Tags: shortcuts, opera

In Opera how can I define a shortcut for cloning a tab? Currently I right click on a tab select `clone tab`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean a keyboard shortcut, go to `Preferences` > `Advanced` > `Shortcuts`, and edit your keyboard setup. If you haven't got a custom one yet, you may want to select the "Opera Standard" one, hit "Duplicate", and select the copy (this bit isn't obvious, duplicating a setup doesn't automatically select it), and click "Edit...". (You may want to rename it, too, just to make sure you'll always know it's your custom one.)

In the "Edit Keyboard Setup" dialogue, expand and select "Browser Window" and click the "New..." button to the right. Type your desired shortcut (space-separated, with the main key before the modifiers - for instance, "d shift ctrl", or have a look at some of the other key definitions in there, especially if you're on a Mac) in the field on the left, and the action "Duplicate page" on the right (double-click to edit a field).

Once you've added the shortcut, click "OK" to close the dialog, and, making sure you've selected your custom Keyboard setup, click "OK" to close the Preferences. Your keyboard shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in the example) should now duplicate the current tab.

If you want a mouse gesture rather than a keyboard shortcut, it's quite similar - duplicate and edit your custom mouse setup to add a new gesture and set "Duplicate page" as the action to have the mouse gesture clone your tab.